# Add specific text at the end of URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Using .htaccess I want to add specific text at the end of my URL. In the example below I want to add the word "Hello" at the end of the URL when the user visits

```
https://example.com/aboutus/
```

URL typed in by user :

```
https://example.com/aboutus/
```

URL rewritten to :

```
https://example.com/aboutus/Hello
```

Note : If the user types in

```
https://example.com/aboutus/Hello
```

the URL should stay

```
https://example.com/aboutus/Hello
```

I am new to .htaccess

Comment: "URL rewritten to" - I assume you mean _redirect_? (Without more context it wouldn't make sense to "rewrite" such a request.)

Comment: The directory "Hello" doesn't exist on the server. All requests to "https://example.com/aboutus/" should go to "https://example.com/aboutus/Hello"

Comment: Yes, by the sounds of it, this should be a "redirect", not a "rewrite". What you describe here would seem to be a simple `/a` to `/b` redirect. The fact that you are "appending" a word to the original URL is largely irrelevant, since you've only give one static example? Have you tried to implement anything?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while that I worked with .htaccess, but there ya go:

```
# Check if your request already containts 'Hello' at the end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Hello/?$
# Apply the rule for the path "/aboutus" or "/aboutus/"
RewriteRule ^aboutus/?$ /aboutus/Hello [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The condition isn't doing anything since the `RewriteRule` has already established that the URL is `aboutus` (or `aboutus/`) only.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would seem to be a simple `a` to `b` redirect. The fact that you are "appending" a string to the URL is largely irrelevant since you've only given one static example.

Without more information, the following would satisfy the criteria in the question:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/aboutus/$ /aboutus/Hello
```

`RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive. (As opposed to mod_rewrite.)

`^/aboutus/$` is a regular expression that matches exactly `/aboutus/`.

You can't use the more simple `Redirect` directive here because this uses simple prefix-matching and would result in a redirect loop (since you are appending a string to the URL that is matched).

You could use a backreference to save repetition. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/aboutus/$ $0Hello
```

Where `$0` contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the first argument.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch